# Split set of files based on size in MB with Python

Tags: python, file-io, split, directory, filesize

Is there any way to have a function in Python that can walk a folder with a list of files & separate the list into "partitions" (which will become folders) based on total size of the files in each partition/folder in megabytes? I'm not sure how to start with this or what to do first.

Comment: Yes! Start with `import os`. Give it a try and let us know if you run into problems.

Comment: (●▽● ) !! Sweet! I'll give it a college try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a starting point, not a solution in a can:

- Use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to scan a whole directory tree. If you only need to scan one folder, not a whole tree, you can optimize a bit without sacrificing simplicity (particularly on Windows) on Python 3.5 with the new [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) function that will give you `stat` info for free on Windows (and make it accessible as a lazily cached value on *NIX systems). On earlier versions of Python, a third party `scandir` module on PyPI provides the same interface.
- If not using `os.scandir`, you'd use [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) to get file sizes
- Use a `collections.defaultdict(set)` to map from file sizes in MB to a `set` of files that round to that size (or just process the files as you go instead of storing in a container at all). Alternatively, sort with `sorted` `key`-ed on the size and use `itertools.groupby` (with whatever MB granularity you like) to group the resulting files.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! :D You even gave me the info about which Python version to use, this is very helpful.